# Convert combination value into dummies in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a dataset like this:

```
id<-c(1:6)
value<-c(" ","1", "1 6","1 777"," ", " ")
df<-data.frame(id, value)
```

Now I would like to convert it as dummy variable for each value, and use 0 and 1 to represent "yes" and "no". In other word, instead of count the combination value, i would like to count each value for each observation. for example, the first obs is NA, so only NA is yes, the third obs chose combo value "1" and "6", so in row no.3, the cols"1" and col"6" are marked as "1" (which is yes). Ideally get the table looks like this (plz ignore the dot after the numbers):

```
id 1 6 777 NA
1 0  0  0  1
2 1  0  0  0
3 1  1  0  0
4 1  0  1  0
5 0  0  0  1
6 0  0  0  1
```

i tried use package "fastdummies", my code is like this:

```
df<-dummy_cols(df,
             select_columns="value",
             split="")
```

it does not work very well. Any solution for such case? Thanks a lot.

Also, when it spits out the dummy vars, the cols name like "value_", "value_6", is there any way to show the name as they were as value like "1", "6","777","NA". Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to convert the space elements to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fastDummies)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     na_if(" ") %>% 
     dummy_cols("value", split = " ", remove_selected_columns = TRUE) %>%  
     mutate(across(starts_with('value_'), replace_na, 0))  %>%
     rename_with(~ str_remove(.x, "value_"), starts_with("value_"))
```

-output

```
  id 1 6 777 NA
1  1 0 0   0  1
2  2 1 0   0  0
3  3 1 1   0  0
4  4 1 0   1  0
5  5 0 0   0  1
6  6 0 0   0  1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun. I have one more question that when I apply this code to my real data (which only contain the " ", 1, "1 6", "1 777", "7" and "6", i checked the dataset, there is no date type value), R shows me that "Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". Could you let me know how to fix this issue? Many thanks :)

Comment: @Rstudyer can you show the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: @Rstudyer can you check `traceback()` and see where the issue is

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @akrun. I used those two to check my dataset, it turns out the na_if applied all dataset including two dates vars, and I slightly changed the code to apply the na_if only used on selected var, then it worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help~~!